# How to remember objects to be treated after QuerySet.update()

Tags: django, django-models

I want to update the `bar` attribute of a bunch of `Foo` objects using the `QuerySet`'s `update()` method. Then I want to do something with the modified objects, but I can no more identify them using the `bar` attribute.

Somehow it doesn't work by remembering the ids.

```
old_bar = Bar.objects.get(id=1)
new_bar = Bar.objects.get(id=2)

foo_query = Foo.objects.filter(bar=old_bar)
foo_ids = foo_query.values_list('id', flat=True)

print len(foo_ids), foo_query.count(), Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids).count()
# outputs "42 42 42"

print foo_query.update(bar=new_bar)
# outputs "42"

print len(foo_ids), foo_query.count(), Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids).count()
# outputs "42 0 0"
```

Does the `update()` method modify the ids or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks strange to me. And what's the output if you print `foo_ids` after queryset update?

Comment: The output is a list of ids `[69562, 69574, 70817, ...]`. Actually, I found out that I can do `print Foo.objects.filter(id=foo_ids[0])` after the `update()` and there is an object returned. Is there something wrong about the `id__in=`?

Comment: Alright, found the solution: `foo_ids` was a `ValuesListQuerySet`, so I did `foo_ids = list(foo_query.values_list('id', flat=True))` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Querysets are lazy, so they are evaluated everytime you use them! Therefore in your example `foo_query` will be evaluated more than once and return something different depending on the actual objects in your database. `foo_ids` is therefore not a list of ids, but a `ValuesQueryset` that **evaluates** to a list.

Forcing it evaluate to a list should make your example work, as the ids do not change to reflect the actual state of the database: `foo_ids = list(foo_query.values_list('id', flat=True))`.

Comment: Well, just saw you answered it yourself :/